# Vertical and Horizontal figures on one plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I would like to create sth like the following graph in matplotlib:

[image]

I have `x = [0, 1, ..., 10]`, and for each `x` I have values from range `[0, 60]`. Lets say that the black line is the quantile of values for a given `i` from range `x`. For selected `i` I want to add `horizontally` histogram (with parameter `density = True`) like in the picture with the possibility to control the width of this histogram (in the picture it goes from 2 to 5 but I would like to set fixed width). How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is relatively straightforward with `inset_axes`:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.random.randn(100)
ax.plot(x)
ylim = ax.get_ylim()

histax = ax.inset_axes([0.3, 0, 0.2, 1], transform=ax.transAxes)
histax.hist(x, orientation='horizontal', alpha=0.5 )
histax.set_facecolor('none')
histax.set_ylim(ylim)

plt.show()
```

[image]

You will probably want to clean up the axes etc, but that is the general idea.

Comment: Thanks it works. I hide xticks using `histax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
` but the black horizontal lines are still visible. Do you know how can I hide it too?

Comment: `histax.set_yticks([])` is probably the easiest way

Comment: Oh, you mean the vertical lines?   `histax.axis('off')` gets rid of everything...